# Shiny countdown timer then trigger

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

I use the following code to do a 3-second countdown after a button is clicked. I would like the output to change to something else e.g "Countdown finished" once the countdown hits 0.

How do I listen to the countdown output (which is not an input) in real-time to see when the countdown hits 0 and trigger something else?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("do", "Click Me"),
  verbatimTextOutput("eventTimeRemaining")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {


  observeEvent(input$do, {

    EventTime <- Sys.time() + 3


    output$eventTimeRemaining <- renderText({
            invalidateLater(1000, session)
            round(difftime(EventTime, Sys.time(), units='secs'))
                                            })

  })



}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR: Make the `EventTime` reactive

One thing to note, the way you have it set up now, the output is getting recreated every time the `observeEvent` is triggered. What you really want is it to just get updated based on some trigger. Here's the code for the server function:

```
 server <- function(input, output, session) {

  EventTime <- reactiveVal()

  observeEvent(input$do,{
    EventTime(Sys.time() + 3)
  })

  output$eventTimeRemaining <- renderText({

    req(input$do)

    timeLeft <- round(difftime(EventTime(), Sys.time(), units='secs'))

    if(timeLeft > 0){
      invalidateLater(1000, session)
      msg <- timeLeft
    } else {
      msg <- "<Time expired message>"
    }

    msg

  })

}
```

Here's what's going on: Set up the text out, but the `req` will prevent anything from being displayed until the input button is clicked at least once. When the input button is clicked, the time is captured in `EventTime` reactive. This in turn (along with the click) trigger an update to the text out. If there's still time left the message displays the time and sets the output to invalidate a second later. If time is expired, your final message is displayed and importantly, the output stops updating (at least until the button is clicked again).